# How to use Sketch to create a six sides polygon with trapezoidals inside it?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, sketch-app, background

As you can see my solution is to make a 6 sided polygon manually and it is NOT pixel perfect. I need it pixel perfect to make a repeating background using this as the base.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Create an equilateral triangle and use copies of it to construct a hexagon using Sketch's excellent snapping capabilities. Then make unions of triangles to create trapezoidals.[image: process description]

Comment: Woh! your share is so perfect!!! any chance you can share the file with me? Never mind I got it works now. Thank you.

Comment: I want it to have a nice inner border for trapezoidal? Using this method the border for triangle still appears. See updated questions (last screenshot)

Comment: Sometimes the antialiasing is not perfect when two shapes that are not pixel aligned meet. One simple solution that gives perfect result is to create multiple copies of your final hexagon and stack them on top of each other (cmd+d a couple of times). Any pixels that are semitransparent will quickly add upp to have 100% opacity.

Comment: Oh, I have spend few hours on this and still have no clue.

Comment: And I'm not sure what does you last comment means. Could you please a sample. Thank you very much.

Comment: http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=04994425098476547383

Comment: Actually antialiaising in nearly allr rendering engines show trough on perfectly shared edges because they use coverage as assumption, leading to a error